# Why does GetAttribute("disabled") return "true" not "disabled"?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-8, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nunit

In some of my tests I have to confirm that some select2 dropdowns are disabled when certain flags are set. To confirm this I found that the strategy below seemed to work:

```
Assert.True(element.GetAttribute("disabled").Equals("true"));
```

When I inspect the element I see `disabled="disabled"`. My question is why does the string returned from `GetAttribute = "true"` not "disabled"?

Comment: I just ran into this issue, did you have a work around?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

Certain attributes seem to only return Boolean values, whether the actual value is "true" or "false". Disabled is one of them. Linked page lists all the attributes considered to be Boolean values, any other attribute should return the attribute's value.

Quoting the most relevant part of the linked page :

> "The following are deemed to be "boolean" attributes, and will return either "true" or null: async, autofocus, autoplay, checked, compact, complete, controls, declare, defaultchecked, defaultselected, defer, **disabled**, draggable, ended, formnovalidate, hidden, indeterminate, iscontenteditable, ismap, itemscope, loop, multiple, muted, nohref, noresize, noshade, novalidate, nowrap, open, paused, pubdate, readonly, required, reversed, scoped, seamless, seeking, selected, spellcheck, truespeed, willvalidate ". [[Selenium : WebElement.getAttribute()](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That explanation is completely missing form the .NET API docs.

Comment: Well, if you are using Selenium, that link IS (part of) the documentation. It isn't something that you would ever see in the Microsoft .NET docs (MSDN) if that is what you are referring to. Anyways, no worries, glad I could help out!

Comment: Sorry, I meant Selenium .Net API docs
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html

Comment: The first link in the answer is broken: https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html